# PHP: Get variations from an array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

Is it possible if i use this array

```
 array ( 
        [0] => array ( 
            [0] => 'Size',
            [variation_id] => array ( 
                [0] => 'S',
                [1] => 'M',
                [2] => 'L',
                [3] => 'XL'
            ) 
        ),
        [1] => array ( 
            [0] => 'Length',
            [variation_id] => array ( 
                [0] => '14 Inches',
                [1] => '18 Inches'8
            ) 
        ) 
    )
```

To get the Result like this

Variation Name

1. variation (S, 14 Inces)
2. variation (S, 18 Inces)
3. variation (M, 14 Inces)
4. variation (M, 18 Inces)
5. variation (L, 14 Inces)
6. variation (L, 18 Inces)
7. variation (XL, 14 Inces)
8. variation (XL, 18 Inces)

if no please give me some advice..
Thanks

Comment: Use two `foreach` for it.

Comment: Can u give an example please?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use two [foreach](http://php.net/foreach)

```
$data = array (
    array (
        'Size',
        'variation_id' => array (
            'S',
            'M',
            'L',
            'XL'
        )
    ),
    array (
        'Length',
        'variation_id' => array (
            '14 Inches',
            '18 Inches',
        )
    )
);
$sizes = $data[0]['variation_id'];
$lengths = $data[1]['variation_id'];

$result = array();
foreach($sizes as $size)
    foreach($lengths as $length)
        $result[] = "variation ($size, $length)";

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thanks you.. this script running well, can u help me with 2nd question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044996/php-no-nead-twice-array-looping